# Multiple public domain names for a MOSS 2007 internet facing web site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to get multiple domain names pointing to the same moss 2007 internet facing web site ?  I know one can use zones, and map each zone to a single different public URLs, but there's only 5 zones available per moss site.

I need something like 10 domain names to point to same moss web site.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an "**Internal URL**" and connect it to the zone that you prefer the most.
There is no restrictions to the number of "Internal URLs" that one might have.